# Is it possible to run v-for after created() is complete?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to add the corresponding avatar to each notification, so I can display it along with the rest of notification, but I can't figure this out on my own. Here's the HTML inside the Vue.js template:

```
    <li class="notification" v-for="(notification, index) in notifications">
        <a>
            <span class="image">
                <img :src="notification.avatar" alt="Avatar" />
            </span>

        <span class="link">
            <span v-text="notification.data.sender_name"></span>
        </span>

        <span class="message" v-text="notification.data.message"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

And here's the js:

```
data() {
    return {
        user: this.initialUser,
        notifications: this.initialUser.unread_notifications,
    }
},

created() {
    let self = this;
    self.notifications = this.initialUser.unread_notifications;

    self.notifications.forEach(function(notification) {
        if(notification.data.sender_id) {
            axios.post(self.user.path + '/get-avatars', {
                id: notification.id,
            }).then((response) => {
                let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
                    notification.avatar = response.data;
                });
            });
        }
    });
},
```

The problem that I'm having is that the `v-for` runs before the `created()` method, so that my notifications object does not have the avatar property at the time the v-for is performed.

Is there any way I could run the v-for only after the created() has been completed?

Thank you!

Comment: `this.$set(notification, 'avatar', response.data)` will trigger the reactivity

Comment: That's awesome and it worked! Well, it was actually `self.$set(notification, 'avatar', response.data)` but nevertheless you had it right! You can add this as a solution for other to see it aswell, and I will mark it as the right answer. Thanks a million! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`this.$set(notification, 'avatar', response.data)`

to trigger reactivity manually. You need to have an `avatar`  property beforehand in order to automatically have reactivity when doing `notification.avatar = ...`. If you dont have the property, you need to use this helper function from Vue.

This can be a problem with **objects** as well as **arrays**.

For more info see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something here, there's no reason to delay executing the `v-for` directive. All you need to do is ensure that the `notification` object has the `avatar` field already set, even if it is set to `undefined`. You can do this from the parent, or with a computed property that clones the incoming objects with the property set: `this.initialUser.unread_notifications.map(notification => Object.assign({ avatar: undefined },  notification)`

If you don't want a notification to render until the avatar is loaded, you can either:

1. Add `v-if="!!notification.avatar"` to the `li` element. (The standard Vue linter will advise against this; I happen to think it's quite convenient. It essentially filters your output according to the condition.)
2. Create a computed property, say `unread_notifications_with_avatars`, which is equal to (e.g.) `this.initialUsers.unread_notifications.filter(notification => !!notification.avatar)`, and use this in your `v-for` directive.

If you really want to not render the list until all the avatar calls are complete, there are ways to do that as well (for example using `Promise.all(...).then(() => this.showTheList = true)`). It's a bit trickier though and it doesn't look to me like you actually need it in this case.